# Scala traits: defining nested attributes

Tags: scala, traits

I'm very beginner Scala programmer who's coming from Java.  I'm trying to build an understanding of Scala's traits, as a superior alternative to Java's interfaces.  In this case, I want to create a trait which, when implemented, will require an object to have attributes, and one or more of those attributes will themselves be objects with required traits.  The following code demonstrates what I want, but it doesn't currently work.

```
trait Person{
  def name: String
  def age: Int
  def address extends Address

}

trait Address{
  def streetName: String
  def streetNumber: Int
  def city: String
}

object aPerson extends Person {
  override val name = "John"
  override age = 25
  override address = object { //this doesn't work
     def streetName = "Main St."
     def streetNumber = 120
     def city = "Sometown"
  }
}
```

So I want the `Person` trait to require the object to have an `Address` attribute, which itself has some required attributes.  The compiler doesn't like the above code defining the `address` in `aPerson`.

What's the right way to do this?

**Bonus question**: Let's say the `Address` trait is only used here.  Is there a way to define the `Address` trait anonymously inside the `Person` trait so it won't clutter the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
trait Person{
  val name: String
  val age: Int
  val address: Address
}

trait Address{
  val streetName: String
  val streetNumber: Int
  val city: String
}

object aPerson extends Person {
  val name = "John"
  val age = 25
  val address: Address = new Address { //this now works
    val streetName = "Main St."
    val streetNumber = 120
    val city = "Sometown"
  }
}
```

The `Address` trait can be made anonymous, but then traits like `Person` can't reference it because it has no named type.

```
trait Person{
  val name: String
  val age: Int
//val address: ?type?
}

object aPerson extends Person {
  val name = "John"
  val age = 25
  val address = new { //this also works
    val streetName = "Main St."
    val streetNumber = 120
    val city = "Sometown"
  }
}

aPerson.address.city  //res0: String = Sometown
```

Comment: The second suggestion regarding making it anonymous doesn't work, because without a named type, other code can't do type-checking, which totally makes sense.  So I guess I just won't declare it anonymously.  But the first piece of code works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can override a `def` with an `object`.

```
trait Person {
  def name: String
  def age: Int
  def address: Address
}

object aPerson extends Person {
  val name = "John"
  val age = 25
  object address extends Address {
    val streetName = "Main St."
    val streetNumber = 120
    val city = "Sometown"
  }
}
```